SQL Server text output file formatting
I am trying to create a nightly job with a query to email an output file in text format. My issue is, when I run it currently, the output that is sent in the email looks awful.
Here is my query:
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
              @recipients = 'user@organization.org',
              @subject = 'Lockouts',
              @query = N'SELECT [UserName]
                            ,[Email]
                                ,CAST (LockoutEndDateUtc AS DATE) AS LockoutEndDateUtc
                                ,[LockoutEnabled]
                                ,CAST (LastLoginDateUtc AS DATE) AS LastLoginDateUtc
              FROM [AccountInformationOnline].[dbo].[ApplicationUsers]
              WHERE LockoutEndDateUtc IS NOT NULL
              AND LockoutEndDateUtc >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))  --Returns                      
                                                              results from last 7 days
              ORDER BY LockoutEndDateUtc DESC;',
              @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
              @query_attachment_filename = 'Lockouts.txt'

Is there an easy way to make the text file look readable within the query? Any and all help would be awesome. Thanks in advance.
Have tried to use XML, but I'm a true DBA, not a developer, so this is kind of new to me.

Yip, the easy way is to send your emails from an application that is designed for sending emails, not from a database which is designed for storing data.
